# Django Views Parameters

Tags: python, django

I have made a Django Model like this:

**Student** Class,

**Subject** Class - foreign key to **Student** Class

**Grade** Class - foreign key to **Subject** Class

In my understanding, I have set it up so that:

Multiple **Students** can have multiple **Subjects**, and each **Subject** that students are in will have different **Grades**.

I am trying to make a separate page for each **student**, so each page will display the **Student** name, **Subjects** the student is taking, and the **Grade** for each **Subject**.

This is my views.py file for the page (I have set the url as /(student_pk)/ for each student's page)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Student, Subject, Grade

def detail(request, student_pk, subject_pk):
stud = Student.objects.get(pk=student_pk)
subject = stud.subject_set.all()
sub = Subject.objects.get(pk=subject_pk)
grade = subject.grade_set.all()

context = {
    'student_pk':student_pk,
    'subject':subject,
    'grade':grade,
}
return render(request, 'studentinfo/detail.html', context)
```

The views parameter to my knowledge can only take 2.
Is this the right way to do so? I have a feeling it is not and that my models itself is setup wrong for my purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, changed models so that grades were part of Subject class and it seems to have solved my question for now.